# Tizen Wearable communication

Tags: tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-galaxy-gear

I wanted to know if there is a way for two samsung wearables to communicate with each other directly through an application.
Is there any documentation?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible right now. For any communication you need a host device, which is a mobile phone right now.

Answer (score 0):

or workaround by hacking some IR or Audio or Camera/Screen communication ... I have this in mind for long but never started project , any hints welcome